# How to create database and tables for each new user in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

> I want to create database for each user with unique name. and tables
>   in it.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['createCom'])) {            
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";    
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $company = $_REQUEST['companyname'];
        $ran = rand(0,100);    
        $random = $ran;         
        // Create database
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE rnadom";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Database created successfully";
            header('Location: societyList.php');
        }    
        $conn->close();
```

> if i used normal name like `random` it will create db. but if i used
>   `$random` variable it's not creating database.  and same time i want
>   to create some tables within that database.

Comment: It is a __very bad__ approach

Comment: Very nearly the **worst idea ever**

Comment: How about adding a userId field to the relevant tables instead?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmmm, not sure, I've seen some *very* bad ideas here...

Comment: @jeroen Good point, well made! :)

Comment: @jeroen I have amended my comment appropriately I hope

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hard to disagree with that :-)

Comment: Lol.  Why isn't this question downvoted?  Like 10times

Comment: @Akintunde The question is not that bad, the idea behind it is.

Comment: By the way, to answer your question, if you want to use an integer as a table name (*extremely not recommended* either...), you need to quote it in backticks in your sql statements.

Comment: I don't know what the goal of this is, but a separate database for each user is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: unless the OP is making a CMS ? and is doing it as part of the CMS setup.. possible right ? doesn't seem very likely, but maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

Table name can't start with digit. You can use constant value + number.
Like userdb_1, userdb_2 and so on. But I don't understand how will you connect to created database later if it has random name.